# Haskell IORef - an answer vs. a function to get an answer

Tags: haskell, io, closures, do-notation, ioref

I'm trying to understand how `IORefs` are really used, and I'm having trouble following the sample code I found on https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/spring15/lectures/12-unsafe.html

```
newCounter :: IO (IO Int)
newCounter = do
  r <- newIORef 0
  return $ do
    v <- readIORef r
    writeIORef r (v + 1)
    return v

printCounts :: IO ()
printCounts = do
  c <- newCounter
  print =<< c
  print =<< c
  print =<< c
```

When `printCounts` executes "`c <- newCounter`", why doesn't `c` get the result of doing the work in the `newCounter` "`return $ do`" block, which seems like it should get assigned to the constant "`IO 0`" the first time it is called and then never change?  Instead, `c` seems to get assigned the function defined in that "`return $ do`" block, which is then executed anew every time `printCounts` gets to another "`print =<< c`."  It seems that the answer somehow lies in `newCounter` having the double nested "`IO (IO Int)`" type, but I can't follow why that makes `c` a function to be re-executed when called instead of a constant evaluated just once.

Comment: A side note: you should not have an `IO (IO Int)` type, this is bad style.

Comment: @AJFarmar, I don't see anything bad about that style; it's just providing a counter with a restricted interface.

Comment: Well, I suppose it would actually be better to provide an abstract `Counter` type....

Comment: let-over-lambda to bind-over-return. :)

Comment: @AJFarmar I wouldn't use `IO (IO Int)` just for a counter: but that pattern is often the best way of expressing something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think of `IO` as a type of programs. `newCounter :: IO (IO Int)` is a program that outputs a program. More precisely, `newCounter` allocates a new counter, and returns a program that, when run, increments the counter and returns its old value. `newCounter` doesn't execute the program it returns. It would if you wrote instead:

```
newCounter :: IO (IO Int)
newCounter = do 
  r <- newIORef 0
  let p = do              -- name the counter program p
        v <- readIORef r
        writeIORef r (v + 1)
        return v
  p          -- run the counter program once
  return p   -- you can still return it to run again later
```

---

You can also use equational reasoning to unfold `printCounts` into a sequence of primitives. All versions of `printCounts` below are equivalent programs:

```
-- original definition
printCounts :: IO ()
printCounts = do
  c <- newCounter
  print =<< c
  print =<< c
  print =<< c

-- by definition of newCounter...

printCounts = do
  c <- do
    r <- newIORef 0
    return $ do
      v <- readIORef r
      writeIORef r (v + 1)
      return v
  print =<< c
  print =<< c
  print =<< c

-- by the monad laws (quite hand-wavy for brevity)
-- do
--   c <- do
--     X
--     Y
--   .....
-- =
-- do
--   X
--   c <- 
--     Y
--   .....
--
-- (more formally,
--  ((m >>= \x -> k x) >>= h) = (m >>= (\x -> k x >>= h)))

printCounts = do
  r <- newIORef 0
  c <-
    return $ do
      v <- readIORef r
      writeIORef r (v + 1)
      return v
  print =<< c
  print =<< c
  print =<< c

-- c <- return X
-- =
-- let c = X
--
-- (more formally, ((return X) >>= (\c -> k c)) = (k X)

printCounts = do
  r <- newIORef 0
  let c = do
        v <- readIORef r
        writeIORef r (v + 1)
        return v
  print =<< c
  print =<< c
  print =<< c

-- let-substitution

printCounts = do
  r <- newIORef 0
  print =<< do
        v <- readIORef r
        writeIORef r (v + 1)
        return v
  print =<< do
        v <- readIORef r
        writeIORef r (v + 1)
        return v
  print =<< do
        v <- readIORef r
        writeIORef r (v + 1)
        return v

-- after many more applications of monad laws and a bit of renaming to avoid shadowing
-- (in particular, one important step is ((return v >>= print) = (print v)))

printCounts = do
  r <- newIORef 0
  v1 <- readIORef r
  writeIORef r (v1 + 1)
  print v1
  v2 <- readIORef r
  writeIORef r (v2 + 1)
  print v2
  v3 <- readIORef r
  writeIORef r (v3 + 1)
  print v3
```

In the final version, you can see that `printCounts` quite literally allocates a counter and increments it three times, printing each intermediate value.

One key step is the let-substitution one, where the counter program gets duplicated, which is why it gets to run three times. `let x = p; ...` is different from `x <- p; ...`, which runs `p`, and binds `x` to the result rather than the program `p` itself.